# Draw multiple objects from different buffers (arrays switching)

Tags: c#, opengl, vbo

Currently I'am trying to draw multiple object using number of buffers.

I'am not sure that I switch buffers for drawing in proper way and cannot figure out how to do it.

I have 2 arrays:

- `quad_strip2` in amount contains 34 elements (objects to draw) and each of element for it's `QUAD_STRIP` use 52 vertices (1767 vertices in total).
- `quad_strip3` contains 48 elements with 26 vertices for `QUAD_STRIP` (1247 vertices in total).

**Initialization code**

```
        gl.GenBuffers(2, Buffers);

        //SKIPED MATRICES AND SHADERS INITIALIZATION

        float[] quad_strip2 = new float[]
        {
            // COUNT OF ELEMENTS: 34
            // COUNT OF VERTICES: 52

            -19.66171f, 8.161709f, 2f, //0
            -19.66171f, 8.161709f, 4f, //1
             ........
            -19.66171f, -6.838291f, 35f, //1767

        };

        float[] quad_strip3 = new float[]
        {
            // COUNT OF ELEMENTS: 48
            // COUNT OF VERTICES: 26
            -0.8537037f, 7.25f, 2f, //0
            -0.8537037f, 7.25f, 4f, //1
             ........
            -20f, -3.25f, 34.45f, //1247
        };

        //bind first buffer
        gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[0]);

        //fill buffer with vertices
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (float* verts = quad_strip2)
            {
                var prt = new IntPtr(verts);

                gl.BufferData(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_strip2.Length * sizeof(float), prt,
                    OpenGL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            }
        }

        //bind second buffer
        gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[1]);

        //fill buffer
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (float* verts = quad_strip3)
            {
                var prt = new IntPtr(verts);

                gl.BufferData(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad_strip3.Length * sizeof(float), prt,
                    OpenGL.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

            }
        }

        gl.VertexAttribPointer((uint)Attrib_IDs.vPosition, 3, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, new IntPtr(0));
        gl.EnableVertexAttribArray((uint)Attrib_IDs.vPosition);
```

**Drawing code**

```
    //SKIPED FILLING VERTEX SHADER WITH MATRIXES


     //DRAW ARRAYS
    //binf first array and draw it 
    gl.BindVertexArray(Buffers[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
    {
        gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_QUAD_STRIP, i * 52, 52);
    }


    //binf second array and draw it 
    gl.BindVertexArray(Buffers[1]);
    shaderProgram.SetUniform3(gl, "color", 0, 0.4f, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {
        gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_QUAD_STRIP, i * 26, 26);
    }


    //DRAW WIREFRAMES
    shaderProgram.SetUniform3(gl, "color", 0, 0, 0);
    gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);

    gl.PolygonOffset(1.0f, 1.0f);

    gl.PolygonMode(FaceMode.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Lines);


    gl.BindVertexArray(Buffers[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
    {
        gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_QUAD_STRIP, i * 52, 52);
    }

    gl.BindVertexArray(Buffers[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
    {
        gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_QUAD_STRIP, i * 26, 26);
    }

    gl.PolygonMode(FaceMode.FrontAndBack, PolygonMode.Filled);
```

As result I have such output, which is not looks like what I need to get.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `VertexAttribPointer` call after each of the `BindBuffer` calls in your drawing code. `VertexAttribPointer` applies to the currently bound buffer. Your current code has only one `VertexAttribPointer` call in the init code, which happened while `Buffers[1]` was called. So all your draw calls will use vertex data from that buffer.

EDIT: I also just notice that you use `BindVertexArray` in your draw code. Vertex array objects (VAO) are different kinds of objects from vertex buffers (VBO), and you can't just use the id of a VBO for a `BindVertexArray` call. To get this all working without VAOs for now, you can remove the `VertexAttribPointer` call from the init code. Then add two `VertexAttribPointer` calls to your draw code, and replace the `BindVertexArray` with `BindBuffer`, to structure it like this:

```
gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[0]);
gl.VertexAttribPointer((uint)Attrib_IDs.vPosition, 3, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, new IntPtr(0));
for (int i = 0; i < 34; i++)
{
    gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_QUAD_STRIP, i * 52, 52);
}

gl.BindBuffer(OpenGL.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[1]);
gl.VertexAttribPointer((uint)Attrib_IDs.vPosition, 3, OpenGL.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, new IntPtr(0));
shaderProgram.SetUniform3(gl, "color", 0, 0.4f, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
{
    gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.GL_QUAD_STRIP, i * 26, 26);
}
```

The other option is that you really use Vertex Array Objects (VAO) all the way. For that to work, you have to create those objects in the init code (`glGenVertexArrays`), and bind them while setting up the state for each buffer. They allow you to set up all your state during setup, and then only make a single bind call when you get ready to draw. You should be able to find code examples for that with some searching.

Comment: can you provide small code snippet to explain your answer? what parameter in gl.VertexAttribPointer should specify my buffer?

Comment: It's not an argument of `VertexAttribPointer` that specifies a buffer. It matters what buffer is currently bound when the call is made. I'll add to the answer.